# Reuse same style settings for chloropleth maps based on different datasets

Tags: qgis, style

I am new to QGIS. I have been using MapInfo for a couple of years, but I am considering to switch to QGIS. So far I like it, but there are some things that I haven't found out yet.

I want to make multiple graduated chloropleth maps based on a varying set of data but with the same graduated/rule based style.

For example, I have a polygon vector maps with postal code areas and would like to give the polygons a color based on the drivetime to a certain location A.

I can make this style as a graduated style or as a rule based style and save it.

Next, I need to make the exact same map for a different dataset, say drivetime to location B. I want to reuse the same settings (colors en cut-off points for the categories).

In mapinfo this was very easy:
Import an excel file with different datasets in each column-> make 1st map and save the thematic map settings -> Make a new map based on a new column but with the saved thematic map settings.

How do I do this in QGIS without 
-having to remake the graduated style each time (saving a graduated style remembers which column was used and is gone when you change it) 
or 
-redefining all rules in the rule-based style?

Or is there a way to make a batch of maps that does work in QGIS 1.8? The tutorial on batching maps does not work anymore in 1.8 (http://www.qgis.nl/2012/07/28/series-kaarten-genereren/?lang=en )

Hope someone can help me.

THanks in advance,

niels

Answer (score 3):

In the style panel, you can click on "Save Style..." (bottom right of the style window) for your first map. When you want to style the second map, you can click on "Load Style..." and load the style of your previous map.

Sometimes, I have to set up again the parameter setting which attribute column is used for the symbolization, but otherwise it reapplies the same style.
It also saves parameters about scale-dependency and labels (if that is something you use)