# QGIS style save issues

Tags: qgis, symbology

I have a map that I want to do graduated chloropleth maps for each year over 10 years, and I would like to use the same graduations for each year.

I know this [was asked earlier](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58869/reuse-same-style-settings-for-chloropleth-maps-based-on-different-datasets) and therefore I know that I save it as a style and then load it for each new year, but I'm having problems with the save style/load style function in qgis - every time I load the style the data converts back to the original year.

Has anyone else had this problem and figured out a solution? I'm using qgis 2.2.0 valmiera (desktop).

Comment: Have you tried using the "Copy Style" function. You can right click on the layer you want to copy the style from and then click "Copy Style". You then right click on the one you want to paste the style to and click "Paste style".

Comment: How is your data organized? Do you have one file with the yearly values in different columns? Or do you have one file per year?

Comment: I have a column with the different LGA names, and a column for each year.